# How to consume ISwapChainPanelNative interface from SwapChainPanel IntPtr

Tags: c++-cx

From C# code I'm creating Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel instance and getting its IntPtr like this:

```
    WinRT.IObjectReference nativeObject = ((IWinRTObject)MySwapChainPanel).NativeObject;
    IntPtr panelIntPtr = nativeObject.ThisPtr;

    var cli = new MyCliClass();
    cli.SetRenderer(panelIntPtr);
```

And in C++/CLI project I'm trying to use it like this:

```
#include <d3d11_2.h>
#include <d2d1_2.h>
#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>

void TestPlayerCli::MyCliClass::SetRenderer(System::IntPtr swapChainPtr)
{
    ISwapChainPanelNative* panelNative;
    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(swapChainPtr.ToPointer())->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&panelNative));
    //not working either
    //panelNative = (ISwapChainPanelNative*)swapChainPtr.ToPointer();

    IDXGISwapChain2* m_swapChain;
    //init m_swapChain code...
    HRESULT hr = panelNative->SetSwapChain(m_swapChain);
}
```

What would be the proper way to get ISwapChainPanelNative object from provided swapChainPtr in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WinUI3 you need to #include <**microsoft**.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h> rather than <**windows**.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>.

Comment: Just to clarify, if someone else need is. I created C++/WinRT component project from WinUI3 (preview 3 atm) template and included #include <microsoft.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. But I wonder, why have you assigned new IID `63aad0b8-7c24-40ff-85a8-640d944cc325` to the exact same, and binary compatible, COM interface, which already had the `f92f19d2-3ade-45a6-a20c-f6f1ea90554b` one assigned in another header? You have broken more than one third party library by doing that.